# order of columns in primary key in cratedb

Tags: cratedb

Does the order of columns in the primary key impact the performance of related queries depending on the order of columns given in the select statement?

Example:

```
primary key (col1, col2, col3);

select col2, col3 from table;
```

-> would this select use the pk index?

```
select col3,col1,col2 from table;
```

-> would this select use the pk index?

Answer (score 2):

No the order is not relevant.
But the primary key index is only used if all primary key columns will be used inside a **where** clause (like all indices).

`select ... from table where col1 = ... and col2 = ... and col3 = ...;`

Comment: out of curiosity, where did you get that information from? The documentation is hardly ever helping me